# Fetching specific data through .Select in vb

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, select

I got this code from [vbForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?628877-Counting-Particular-Letter-Occurrences-in-a-String) in which gets distinct values of floors in `Floor` column. (I use this to populate the combobox)

```
Dim names = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() Select row.Field(Of Integer)("Floor") Distinct
```

I was thinking, is there a way to get the *distinct floors* in a chosen `Building`(*another column*). Something like:
*SELECT Distinct Floor FROM Building = 'Megamart'*
sorry if the line is off, not good at this. But potentially something like that. What I need is, get all the `Floor` data from which `Building` I choose. Say I want megamart, then add items to comboBox which are `Floor` datas from megamart.

**UPDATE** I tried this one:

```
Dim names = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() _
                Select row.Field(Of String)("Building") & row.Field(Of Integer)("Floor") Distinct
```

But it seems to only concat the data from building + floor. (*megamart1*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
Dim floors = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() _
             Where row.Field(Of String)("Building").Contains("Megamart") _
             Select row.Field(Of Integer)("Floor") Distinct
```

Comment: I was about to edit Anto's answer to that. Anyway thanks

Comment: Almost i have done it, just syntax error...to be honest i have never worked on linq or any OR mapping tools , and this is my first work on it...i did it with some input from Stackoverflow....

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim names = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() where row.Building = 'Megamart' Select row.Field(Of Integer)("Floor") Distinct
```

check this please......

Comment: 'Dim names = From row In FbuildingSettings.camButtonDtable.AsEnumerable() where row.Building.contains('Megamart') Select row.Field(Of Integer)("Floor") Distinct'

Comment: there is no syntax on `row.Building` - its illegal.